# simulate mutil-touch event on MacOSX

Tags: macos, events, simulator

I want to "simulate" a multi-touch event for another application . e.g :simulate a zoom-in gesture on Preview.

use CGEventPost() can simulate and post the mouse click event . but there is no function for any MultiTouch event.

Also, there is no function like CGEventCreateMultiTouchEvent...(), thus I don't know if it's achievable by CGEventPost().

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this??? I am struggling with a similar problem a couple of days already, but nothing seems to work :(